# Java - Holding a password for futher processing

Tags: java, security, encryption, passwords

In our system, the data can be re-encrypted to a user. For this purpose, all the data are decrypted and encrypted with a new key. The most important part of the key is the user's password.
The new password is kept only for the period of re-encrypting in the memory.
In the future this should be planned with date and time. But for this I need the password of the user at a later time.

My question: If I have to hold the password, which is the best method?

1. Just in the session (as a plain text very bad!!)
2. encrypted in the session, with key in the database. (Key to decrypt the password separately from the location of the encrypted password). If the re-encryption is pending that password will be decrypt and used.
3. password in the database (again as a plain text very bad!!)

I don't like any of the ideas because all involve a security risk. The second is the most “secure” I think, but maybe someone has a better solution?!

Comment: Why not stored as one-way hash?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately, I have not won anything here. The hash is indeed the password. Whether I on the basis of a password or password hashes of the key generating is not matter. I need to hold it anyway.

Comment: Why you don't create a random key for the session after successful authorization of the user? In my opinion the user password should not be a part of the key.

Comment: I can't describe every detail, but what i called "password" is part of the encryption, let's say dataPassword or dataPin. User authentication is a separated process. But anyways the problem is still the same: How to hold the pin/password/sessionHash etc. for a long time. Even if i generate a random key, then this is the key to protect.